# Is esri-leaflet officially an Esri project on github?

Tags: esri-leaflet

Is the information found on github for Esri-leaflet, officially part of the ESRI development team for Leaflet?

What I mean is https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet officially being developed by Esri developers.

I know this may sound like a pedestrian type of questions since Github is a social network for developers but I am a bit confused, and trying to figure out if Esri-Leaflet has been blessed by Esri, or it is  independent project where someone was able to developed an extention for Esri, but is not really part of the official Esri developer community.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  more generically, anything found at https://github.com/Esri can be considered an 'official' project because the url references our 'Organization' (in Github's parlance).

https://help.github.com/articles/what-s-the-difference-between-user-and-organization-accounts/

That being said, some repositories are small-scale one off prototypes and others are the location of an actively developed project.  Because of this, its not always possible for us to provide technical support through normal channels for the code in Github.  When in doubt, open an 'issue'

https://guides.github.com/features/issues/

added 3/23/15:
Just to clarify, Esri Leaflet is an official project and developers *can* contact [Technical Support](http://support.esri.com/phoneSupport#us) through standard channels for assistance.  They are also welcome to file issues in Github if they are under the impression they have encountered a bug.

10/29/15: <s>product</s> > project

Answer (score 4):

It's official: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/07/31/new-esri-open-source-javascript-projects-leaflet-geoservices-js-terraformer-pushlet/

And make sure you spell it Esri... ESRI is so 2009...

Comment: And title-case fixes that? :)

Comment: @mdsumner just trying to keep in line with the marketing materials. We users continue to struggle with this.

Comment: welcome @mnavidad!

Comment: E-S-R-I is more 1990's.

Comment: @Mapperz this brings back memories of happy days http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1148&t=87633